# I am getting this error everytime i test my contract using hardhat

Tags: solidity, nodejs, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, etherjs

**This is the error i am getting while testing my contract with hardhat pls help me to get this**

```
PS E:\vs code files> npx hardhat test
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
× Help us improve Hardhat with anonymous crash reports & basic usage data? (Y/n) · y


    1) Deployment should assign the total supply of the token


  0 passing (4s)
  1 failing

  1) Token Contract
       Deployment should assign the total supply of the token:
     Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=1, expectedCount=2, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:261:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:273:20)
      at Logger.checkArgumentCount (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:332:18)
      at E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:187:12
      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
      at E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
      at populateTransaction (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:152:12)
```

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
contract Token{
    string public name = "HARDHAT TESTING";
    string public symbol = "HHH";
    uint256 public totalsupply = 10000;
    mapping(address=>uint256) balances;
    address owner;
    constructor()
    {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalsupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function balanceof(address _to,uint256 amount) external {
        require(balances[msg.sender] > amount,"not enought tokens");
        balances[msg.sender] -=amount;
        balances[_to] +=amount;
    }
    function showbalance(address account) external view returns(uint256)
    {
        return balances[account];
    }
}
```

**this is my contract**

```
const {expect} = require("chai");

describe("Token Contract",function()
{
    it("Deployment should assign the total supply of the token",async function()
    {
        const [owners] = await ethers.getSigners();  // represent an ethereum account
        console.log("Signers Object",owners);
        const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");  // instance created
        const deploy_token  = await Token.deploy(); // deploy the contract statement
        const ownerbalance = await deploy_token.balanceof(owners.address);  //calling balanceof function of the contract
        console.log(owners.address);
        expect(await ownerbalance.showbalance(owners).to.equal(ownerbalance));
    });
});
```

**My token.js file**

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

`balanceof(address _to,uint256 amount)` must receive 2 args, but you pass only 1

`await deploy_token.balanceof(owners.address)`

P.S. Looks like you use wrong code inside `balanceOf` function. Balance of must show user baalance, but there is a code for `transfer` function.

Answer (score 0):

Fix Your Contract Function Name: In your Solidity contract, rename the function balanceof to transfer.

Run Your Test Correctly: In your test code, you're using the function balanceof in a way that it's not supposed to be used. Instead, use showbalance to check the balance of the owner's address.

Fix the expect Line: In the test, you wrote the expect line incorrectly. You should be comparing the initial balance to '10000'.

Test:

describe("Token Contract", function () {
it("Deployment should assign the total supply of the token", async function () {
const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
const deployed_token = await Token.deploy();
await deployed_token.deployed();

```
const initialOwnerBalance = await deployed_token.showbalance(owner.address);

// This line checks if the owner's initial balance is 10000.
expect(initialOwnerBalance.toString()).to.equal('10000');
```

});
});